# jQuery removeClass on menu when item clicked

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, href, removeclass

Ok so I have this function that when a contact is clicked it adds a class to the user

```
 $(".contactlink").live("click",function(e){
            if(lastclicked == $(this).attr('href'))
            {
            return false;   
            }
            contactinfo = lastclicked.split('/');
            alert(lastclicked);

            lastclicked = $(this).attr('href');
            contactinfo = $(this).attr('href').split("/");
            $("#friend_"+contactinfo[2]).addClass('active');
            loadcontactinfo(contactinfo[2]);
            //alert( contactinfo[2] );
            return false;                                   
        });
```

All is working fine, but this part of the function seems not to be saving it self to the jquery.

```
contactinfo = lastclicked.split('/');
alert(lastclicked);
```

cos when I do lastclicked it does not alert me what the href link which was click was last.

Comment: What do "add a class to the user" and "saving itself to the jquery" mean?

Comment: `lastclicked` will be undefined the first time in. You never actually use the value assigned in this statement: `contactinfo = lastclicked.split('/');` - a few lines later you assign `contactinfo = $(this).attr('href').split("/");` and it is that value that you actually use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure that you are declaring variables with `var` in the proper scope. Try something like:

```
// declare lastclicked before created your click function
var lastclicked = '';
$(".contactlink").live("click",function(e){
    if(lastclicked == $(this).attr('href')) {
       return false;   
    }
    alert(lastclicked);
    // use var for local variables
    var contactinfo = $(this).attr('href').split("/");
    lastclicked = $(this).attr('href');

    $("#friend_"+contactinfo[2]).addClass('active');
    loadcontactinfo(contactinfo[2]);
    //alert( contactinfo[2] );
    return false;                                   
});
```

For a simplified example see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2SAa/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you define lastclicked as a **var** before your function?